# Why can i not run two tkinter windows one after the other with images in both?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Class1():
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('800x800')
        
    def RunWindow(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def CloseWindow(self):
        self.root.quit()
        
        
    def ShowWindow(self):
        image_og = Image.open('IMG_0126.jpg').resize((500, 350))
        self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_og)
        PicLabel = tk.Label(self.root, image = self.image_tk)
        PicLabel.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)
        
        nextButton = tk.Button(self.root,text = 'next', command = self.CloseWindow)
        nextButton.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.8)
    
test = Class1()
test.ShowWindow()
test.RunWindow()
print('yes')
test1 = Class1()
test1.ShowWindow()
test1.RunWindow()
```

When this is run it shows the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 31, in <module>
    test1.ShowWindow()
  File "", line 20, in ShowWindow
    PicLabel = tk.Label(self.root, image = self.image_tk)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3214, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2628, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

And I don't understand why this is happening ? Any help would be appreciated

I need the two objects to run one after the other and for both to display an image.